# How do I put a comma on a textfield if what is used to initialize the textfield is a double?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

How do I put a comma on a textfield if what is used to initialize the textfield is a double?

So, the declared `double` variable is equal to, lets say, 10,000.
I use it to put a "10,000" on a textfield. So, this is what I want to happen...

This kind of result:
[image: This kind of result]

However, what I get is something like this:

[image: What I get]

How do I make the output in the textfield into "24,508.0" (with a comma) instead of just "24508.0"? I was thinking, maybe, I could turn it into an array. But how?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: "boolean variable is equal to ... 10,000" - that one awesome boolean variable... Clearly more than 9000. Some code sample could clarify what you meant.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html

Comment: I'm sorry... what I meant was double... just got mixed up...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a formatted text field. Check out [this link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) for more information. I would also like to note that a Boolean is either true or false. Not 10,000.

Comment: @Lil'Dunno Ah okay. Hope the link helps some.

Comment: @chrisSadly, I could not understand... It wouldn't run on cmd... I use Notepad++ and cmd...

Comment: @Lil'Dunno NumberFormat nf =NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US) Add that to your code to create a number format that will add commas. Then add JFormattedTextField name = new JFormattedTextField(nf);

Answer (score 0):

```
double d = 10000000.5
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).format(d));
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this piece of code, and why it answers the question?